# class SomeClass in package x cannot be accessed in com.a.y.x

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scalac

I'm attempting to un-Spring IoC several Java classes and load them directly in some Scala code.  Naturally I'm finding that there are name space conflicts between a package like

```
com.a.x.SomeClass
```

and

```
com.a.y.x.SomeClass
```

I've tried using the import name space resolvers like

```
import com.a.y.x.{ SomeClass => YYYSomeClass }
import com.a.x{ SomeClass => XXXSomeClass }
```

That cleans up the imports, but referring to those classes later in the classes show the error as hovers in the Typesafe ScalaIDE, and after clean compilations.

When I compile from the gradle scala plugin, or via the Typesafe ScalaIDE with scala 2.10.2 or 2.10.3, I get the following type of un-useful error messages:

```
class SomeClass in package x cannot be accessed in com.a.y.x
```

The problem occurs if I try to use a class from com.a.y.x that doesn't have a name space conflict.  If I try some of the scalac flags, I've also been able to get a Warning out that's slightly different ( during the typer stage ):

```
class SomeClass in package x cannot be accessed in y.this.x
```

I'd really like to know if there's a way to expand the first package reference.  I'm having trouble setting up an Eclipse project to debug the scalac compiler and I haven't found a scalac flag that adds useful information to the error.

The error occurs when I either try to `ctx.getBean("someClass").asInstanceOf[XXXSomeClass]` or `new XXXSomeClass`.

The `this` reference from the warning makes me think there's some object confusion going on.  I don't think it's classpath issue in the larger project I'm working on because removing one jar removes the ability to resolve imports, however I can't reproduce it with simple example classes in a separate project.

A little more information on the java classes - the different, conflicting java packages are in separate jars that were compiled by a 1.6 flavor of Java.  They are top level, public classes although two are singletons with private constructors and corresponding public static getInstance() methods.

Comment: I would "leave" on the x or y package in such cases and use `x.SomeClass` or `y.SomeClass` (but likely only on one).

Comment: @user2864740 - I tried the full paths w/o imports and was getting the same errors.  I think I've also tried imports from one package and full path to the other, but I'll check again tomorrow.

Comment: @som-snytt - the relationship of the classes is more complicated in some of the cases - I'll post more tomorrow.  The package of the scala class compared to the java is like `package totally.unrelated`.  Could you elaborate on which annotation/s you think I should try?

Comment: @som-snytt - good idea - I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @som-snytt - Unfortunately that didn't work.  I even went so far as to try `x: com.a.x.SomeClass = new com.a.x.SomeClass` for everything in each of the conflicting packages ( as well as removing the corresponding imports ).  The same error persists.

Comment: @som-snytt - thanks for your time.  I think it's just a terrible error message from scalac and some inattention on my part with too many moving parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really is an access error.  I think this is just a poor error message.  The java was compiled separately and accessed from jar files.  I hadn't paid enough attention to the `package private` nature of the classes I wanted to instantiate( I had seen "public" in front of some of them and not carefully checked all of them ).  The name space collisions were a red-herring in this case and actually don't affect the output of the error message.

In some cases, there are public interfaces I can use instead with a little bit of Spring-glue to instantiate the objects and load them into the Scala class.

The scalac error message would have been more helpful if it had the form:

```
class SomeClass in package com.a.y.x cannot be accessed in totally.unrelated
```

where the first package reference is the Java class's package and the trailing package is the package of the Scala class trying to instantiate the Java class.

To recap - the Java class was like:

```
package com.a.y.x.SomeClass

class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass implements SomeInterface
```

and needs to be like:

```
package com.a.y.x.SomeClass

public class SomeClass extends SomeOtherClass implements SomeInterface
```

to not get these access errors.

Since I have more control of the Scala here, on a whim I tried changing the package of a Scala class from `totally.unrelated` to `com.a.x.y` which then compiles cleanly.  As you might guess, that merely defers the error to a run time error -> `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`.  However, the IllegalAccessError from the Java has the description/package order that I think should happen in the compilation error from scalac:

```
...java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.a.y.x.SomeClass from class s.Trouble$delayedInit$body
```